# Check Environment Variable Value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, window

I am trying to check whether the system has a particular environment variable value that *contains a particular string*; e.g.:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin`

I found how to check whether an environment variable *exists* or not:

```
if ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path', 'Machine'))
{
  "Exist in the system!"
}
```

This works, but I need to know how to check whether the value contains a particular substring or not.

Comment: [How to get environment variable value using PowerShell?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-environment-variable-value-using-powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try :

```
$pathContent = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path', 'Machine')
$myPath = "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
if ($pathContent -ne $null)
{
  # "Exist in the system!"
  if ($pathContent -split ';'  -contains  $myPath)
  {
    # My path Exists
    Write-Host "$myPath exists"
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "$myPath does not exist"
  }
}
```

The `-split` operator generate an array of strings in which the `-contains` operator test if `$myPath` is inside.